# How to get the date of another country Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql

I have an application that will be used in several countries at the same time and there are certain PL / SQL processes that must work at night .
But when it's dark in China , not at night in other countries , so the need to know the schedules of different countries.

I hope you can help me .

Greetings.

Comment: I believe what you may want to look for is the this regarding datetime-timezone regions https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081

Comment: v$timezone_names will be your best option to check the times by offset. Also you can use localtimestamp to evaluate the time at each place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that certain PL/SQL processes should run during after work hours in certain countries, then that implies that the PL/SQL processes would only affect data for users in those countries.

If that is true, you can use the DBMS_SCHEDULER package to create windows or schedules for each country/region.  You can specify start dates and repeat intervals that are time-zone specific.  You would then create region specific jobs to run in those windows or schedules.

See http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235 and http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034 for documentation.  Beware: Very complex but very flexible.

Comment: processes affect only the user data corresponding to each country.
I will review what you are commenting seems to me that the solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what your requirements are but you may check data type [TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169).

When you use this data type then all times are always shown in current user session time zone.